# Navigation drawer to QR scanner app android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello I have a problem in creating apps.. I'm relatively new to coding and I'm trying to connect two templates to one app, I have this template app with QR scanner and another template app with navigation drawer activity.. My problem is that I have to add navigation drawer to the qr scanner app or add the qr scanner to fragments in the another app...

My  **QR SCANNER APP is the following**

https://github.com/varvet/BarcodeReaderSample

It's pretty basic it has button and you press it to scan QR code or barcode

Now I want to add navigation drawer there but I really don't know how to because I have tried but they always lead to multiple errors

My Navigation drawer app is the following

MainActivity

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.navigationdrawerexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //add this line to display menu1 when the activity is loaded
        displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_menu1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

        //creating fragment object
        Fragment fragment = null;

        //initializing the fragment object which is selected
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.nav_menu1:
                fragment = new Menu1();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_menu2:
                fragment = new Menu2();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_menu3:
                fragment = new Menu3();
                break;
        }

        //replacing the fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        //calling the method displayselectedscreen and passing the id of selected menu
        displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
        //make this method blank
        return true;
    }


}
```

My menu 1 code where I would want the scanner

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.navigationdrawerexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 18/09/16.
 */


public class Menu1 extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_1, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("Skanneri");
    }
}
```

My activity_main_drawer.xml is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_menu1"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="QR skanneri" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_menu2"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mapmode"
            android:title="Kartta" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_menu3"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
            android:title="Tietoa eri aloista" />

    </group>

</menu>
```

My fragment_menu_1.xml where I would want the button which scans the qr code is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
        android:text="Paina nappia skannataksesi QR-koodin"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT!!!!**
my build.gradle file has the following

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.simplifiedcoding.navigationdrawerexample"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0' //QRCode scanner
    compile 'com.facebook.rebound:rebound:0.3.8' //spring animation


}
```

I really need help, thanks!

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @LaurIvan these are the errors I get http://imgur.com/a/ol9Y0

Comment: Please add the dependencies. You might be missing something.

Comment: @LaurIvan My build.gradle file is on the edit ^^

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing some dependencies, as you only included `core` package. Try to include other packages as well, perhaps `android-core` as your error seems to points to Android-specific package

Answer (score 0):

1. Include the required dependencies first
2. Clean Project
3. Re-build Gradle